# How to add style float right without disabling click option?

Tags: html, css, angularjs

Here is my code:

```
 <div class="form-group">
          <div class="btn-group radio-group" style="margin-right: 10px">
            <label for="female" class="btn btn-default inputStyle"[ngClass]="{active: femaleSelected === 'active', butonStyle: femaleSelected === 'inactive'}">Female
              <input (click)="onClickFemale()"id="female" value="female"></label>
          </div>

          <div class="btn-group radio-group">
            <label for="male" class="btn btn-default inputStyle" [ngClass]="{active: maleSelected === 'active', butonStyle: maleSelected === 'inactive'}">Male
              <input type="radio" (click)="onClickMale()" id="male" value="male"></label>
          </div>
        </div>
```

If I add style on float right on first div, than I cannot click on inputs.

Comment: this works fine for me, what browser are you using?

Comment: Gooooogle Chrome

Comment: I can't reproduce this - it works fine for me. Just to confirm that you are adding style="float:right" to the div with the class form-group?